# remote event receiver not triggered

Tags: sharepoint-addin, azure, remote-event-receiver, add-ins

i followed this [blog](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/steps-to-create-a-remote-event-receiver-for-sharepoint-online-21971.aspx) and successfully deployed my app,if i click on the sharepoint addin, it successfully contact the remote event receiver on azure but if go to the list and add item nothing happens,i tried investigating with fiddler but found that the remote event receiver is not contacted.